# Partial derivative of conditional composite function with multivariate normal

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, multivariable-calculus, gaussian

I would like to find the partial derivative of $f(y)$ with respect to c where $y$ follows multivariate normal/Gaussian density $N(x(t),\sigma^2I_n)$ i.e.

$f(y)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}|\sigma^2I_n|^{-1/2}exp[-1/2(y-x(t))^T|\sigma^2I_n|^{-1}(y-x(t))]$

Here, $x(t)=\dfrac{\exp(z(t))}{\int_a^p \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s}$
and $z(t)=b(t)^Tc + b(t)^TAu$. I could do it if $x(t)$ is a function of $c$, but I am kind of lost at the very beginning since $x(t)$ is a composite function of $c$ i.e $x(t)=g(h(c))$.

N.B. Here the dimensions: $A$ is $p*p$, $b(t)$ is $p*n$, $c$ & $u$ is $p*1$, so $z(t)$ is $n*1$. And $\sigma^2I_n$ is the $n*n$ variance-covariance matrix.

Using the chain rule $\partial f(y)/\partial c= \partial f(y)/\partial x(t) *\partial x(t)/\partial z(t)*\partial z(t)/\partial c$ I have got ,

$\partial z(t)/\partial c= b(t)^T$

$\partial x(t)/\partial z(t) = x(t)b(t)^T - x(t) [\int_a^p exp[{z(s)}]b(s)^tds]/[\int_a^bexp[z(s)]ds$

$\partial f(y)/\partial c = N(x(t),\sigma^2I_n)|\sigma^2I_n|^{-1}(y - x(t)) $

Is it correct? It's looks too complicated, I thought it would be comparatively simple.

Comment: There is not enough context to be able to understand what you are talking about. You will have to be more explicit.

Comment: I am not sure what else I can say, that's all I have(I edited a little bit.), what extra information I need to know to find the derivative/differentials? would you elaborate a little bit.

Comment: What you do mean when you say $f$ follows $N$? $f$ is supposed to be a function, right? Is it an expectation value of some sort?

Comment: Sorry, f is a function and not an expected value of some sort and f doesn't follow normal/gaussian density, it's basically the variable y|u follows normal density, I have edited now.

Comment: But that doesn't explain what "follows" means, you mean $f(y) = e^{-( y- x(t) )^2/(2 \sigma)} /(2\sigma \sqrt{2\pi})$ where $\sigma$ is this number $a^2I$?

Comment: It's for multivariate Gaussian, although I tried if I could do it for univariate case(but also failed). I have tried to make question more clear now.

Comment: Use the chain rule to pull the derivative through each expression $f(y, c) = N( \frac1{\int_a^n \exp(z(s,c)-z(t,c))\,ds}  )$ so that
$$\partial_c f = N'(x(t)) \cdot \frac{-1}{(\int_a^n \exp(z(s,c)-z(t,c))\,ds)^2} \cdot \int_a^n\exp(z(s,c)-z(t,c))\cdot \partial_c(z(s,c)-z(t,c))\,ds $$
The only issue is that if $c$ is a scalar then $z(t)$ is a covector and $\exp(z(t))$ doesn't make sense. If $c$ is a vector then $x(t)$ will be a scalar whereas you want $y$ to be a vector for the multivariate Gaussian so that $y-x$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @s.harp , would you please tell me how do you come up with the expression of f(y,c), I understand the derivative part, but not the f(y,c). And, the dimension of b(t) is p*n, so the dimension of z(t) is basically n*1 and so as the x(t) and y. I have added all the dimension in the post. Using the chain I have got different result that I added in the post.